# Does Firebase charge queries done on database downloaded on the device using disk persistence?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, persistence

I am using Firebase rtdb. I want to download my database for offline capabilities. If there are no changes on the database, do I get charge to the queries done on local copy of realtime database? And if an update is done on the database, with offline capabilities enabled, is the whole database gets downloaded again or just the part that was changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Queries that only use locally cached data are not billed in any way.  Only queries that actually use the Firebase cloud-based services are billed.  The local cache is only synchronized with the pieces of data that actually changed, not the entire thing every time.

Comment: So if I have a locally cached database, my queries will  access the cached database and not the firebase cloud database? Is that right? And if I didn't cached the database, queries will always access the cloud database, hence the charges? I'm quite confused.

Comment: Realtime Database doesn't really have a "locally cached database".  It has a local cache which is used while offline, and it's populated incrementally as you do queries, but the primary data source is the cloud.

Comment: Please forgive me as I'm not yet familiar with programming terms. When I say locally cached database, I meant the copy of database downloaded on my device when I enabled offline capabilites.

Comment: As I said, Realtime Database doesn't really have a "locally cached database" as you describe. It caches the parts of the database that you previously queried, and it works offline as I described in the answer.

Comment: Thanks Doug for having time to clarify my queries. I appreciate it.

Comment: If you found the answer helpful, it's conventional on Stack Overflow to upvote it and accept it as correct.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot. I'm still new here. Already accepted as correct answer. Thank you.